# class argument/variable scope application / argument result references in subsequent argument

Tags: ruby, class, scope

I'm tasked with making an interest calculator with class arguments, but I'm having a hard time applying variables/arguments. I keep getting an argument error (4 for 0). Moreover, how can I properly refer to the `amount` argument result in my `statement' argument? Any suggestions? Can anyone offer insight to help me understand scoping better within this context?

```
class InterestCalculator
  attr_accessor :principal, :rate, :years, :times_compounded

  def intitialize(principal, rate, years, times_compounded)
    @principal, @rate, @years, @times_compounded = principal, rate, years, times_compounded
  end

  def amount
    amount = @principal * (1 + @rate / @times_compounded) ** (@times_compounded * @years)
  end  

  def statement
    "After #{@years} I'll have #{amount} dollars!"
  end
end
```

These are the specs:

```
describe InterestCalculator do

  before { @calc = InterestCalculator.new(500, 0.05, 4, 5) }

  describe "#amount" do
    it "calculates correctly" do
      expect( @calc.amount ).to eq(610.1)
    end
  end

  describe "#statement" do
    it "calls amount" do
      @calc.stub(:amount).and_return(100)
      expect( @calc.statement ).to eq("After 4 years I'll have 100 dollars!")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you expand on how you are executing/running this code? Copy the error message word for word.

Comment: i found out what i was doing wrong. typo on "initialize...."

thank you taking a bit of your time though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've typoed your `initialize` method ("intitialize") so ruby thinks you are still using the default initialize method which takes no arguments, hence the error.

Comment: oh wow... how embarrassing. =\

thank you though! that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Frederick Cheung is correct however they are also looking for the number to be rounded "eq(610.1)"

```html
def amount
    amount = @principal * (1 + @rate / @times_compounded) ** (@times_compounded * @years)
  end
```

Should be...

```html
def amount
    amount = @principal * (1 + @rate / @times_compounded) ** (@times_compounded * @years)
    amount.round(2)
  end
```